# How to get Json Data from IPinfodb.com with MVC WebService/Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, geolocation, asmx

I want to get User's Location based on IP. When user enters website

I used to do it with XMLHTTPREquest in classic asp

how to do it with .net MVC.

I am new to .net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) and [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) classes could help you. As always start by defining a class that will represent your model:

```
public class LocationResult
{
    public string Ip { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string RegionCode { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string ZipPostalCode { get; set; }
    public float Latitude { get; set; }
    public float Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

and then call the service and deserialize the JSON result back to your model:

```
public LocationResult GetLocationInfo(string ip)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        // query the online service provider and fetch the JSON
        var json = client.DownloadString(
            "http://ipinfodb.com/ip_query.php?ip=" + ip + 
            "&output=json&timezone=false"
        );

        // use the JavaScriptSerializer to deserialize the JSON
        // result back to a LocationResult
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Deserialize<LocationResult>(json);
    }
}
```